# My regular expression isn't matching a thing in my java program

Tags: java, regex

I'm Trying to match one of the following 2 examples:

Example input 1:

```
<a href="Substance/acide_flavodique-4454.htm">acide flavodique</a>
```

Example input 2:

```
<a href="Medicament/ciprofloxacine_arrow_750_mg_cp_pellic-71371.htm">CIPROFLOXACINE ARROW 750 mg cp pellic</a>
```

and what i need to print in my file is : 1- acide flavodique :if it matches the first example.
                     2- ciprofloxacine :if it matches the 2nd example.
Is there any problem with my regular expression or something else ?
Thanks in advance!

```
BufferedReader lire = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file1));
            do{         
                String line = lire.readLine();



                if(line == null)
                {
                    break;
                }
                Pattern p = Pattern.compile ("<a href=\"Substance/.+>(.+)</a>|<a href=\"Medicament/.+>(.+)\\s+.+</a>");
                Matcher m = p.matcher(line); System.out.println("match:"+m.group(1)+"\n");
                if (m.matches()) {
                writer.write(line);
                writer.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                }
            }while(true);


            //      }
            writer.close();
        }}}
```

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/72478

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pattern being:

```
<a href=\"Substance/.+>(.+)</a>|<a href=\"Medicament/.+>(.+)\\s+.+</a>
```

This contains a few '/' characters which are considered unescaped delimeters rendering your pattern useless. You can test for such things here: https://www.regex101.com/

Answer (score 1):

The first problem:

> ```
>    Matcher m = p.matcher(line); 
>    System.out.println("match:"+m.group(1)+"\n");
>    if (m.matches()) {
>        // ...
>    }
> ```

This doesn't work, because you must call `m.matches()` first before calling `m.group(1)`.
So this will be better:

```
   Matcher m = p.matcher(line); 
   if (m.matches()) {
       System.out.println("match:"+m.group(1)+"\n");
       // ...
   }
```

The second problem is with the groups.
Given this pattern:

> ```
> Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<a href=\"Substance/.+>(.+)</a>|<a href=\"Medicament/.+>(.+)\\s+.+</a>");
> ```

And these inputs:

```
String line1 = "<a href=\"Substance/acide_flavodique-4454.htm\">acide flavodique</a>";
String line2 = "<a href=\"Medicament/ciprofloxacine_arrow_750_mg_cp_pellic-71371.htm\">CIPROFLOXACINE ARROW 750 mg cp pellic</a>";
```

Both of these lines will match, but the matched part will be in different groups.
For `line1`, "acide flavodique" will be in `.group(1)`,
but for `line2`, "CIPROFLOXACINE ARROW 750 mg cp" will be in `.group(2)`.
This is because in your regular expression you have two `(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling m.group(..) too early. You should first call m.matches(), otherwise you get IllegalStateException.

And by the way, the pattern *is* found (at least the two examples you provide are matched).

Answer (score 0):

Unless you care which one is found, I guess you could combine the two so all that's
needed is a single capture group 1.

```
 #  "<a\\s+href\\s*=\\s*\"\\s*(?:Substance|Medicament)/[^>]+>([\\s\\S]+?)</a>"

 <a \s+ href \s* = \s* " \s* 
 (?: Substance | Medicament )
 / [^>]+ 
 >
 ( [\s\S]+? )                  # (1)
 </a>
```